# xubuntu has cursor issues

Tags: xubuntu

the newly installed xubuntu on my laptop on has synaptics touchpad installed. I face a strange problem that being my cursor automatically shifts to a random position while typing. Ne idea what could be the reason

Answer (score 5):

You probably can fix this by disabling the touchpad while typing.

You have two options.

### Graphical

This will include some additional gnome libs ;)

```
sudo apt-get install tpconfig
```

In tpconfig you will find options to enable/disable tap mouse clicks and to disable touchpad while typing.

### Command line

In the XFCE options, add this command to autostart

```
syndaemon -t -k -i 2 -d
```

[image: Screenshot]

See [man syndaemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/syndaemon.1.html) for a full set of options.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because part of your wrist/hand is over (but not touching) the touchpad.  This happens on my laptop all the time.  I usually disable it and use a mouse.

Check your laptop / netbook manual if there is a **key combination** to disable the touchpad.

Worked for me both in Windows XP and Xubuntu.